# Is there a code coverage tool that works with manual testing?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

In php, is there a tool that can generate a code coverage report **without** using automated unit test cases ?

(basically not using phpunit or similar unit testing frameworks which do a good job generating the report but require unit testcases to be written in php!).

Exactly what I am looking for, is a tool that would generate me a code coverage report based on manual testing performed by a tester.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sheldon,

Have you heard of Xdebug? I'm using this and it is fantasic! I'm using Ubuntu 8.04 and it is available via the package repository (apt-get).

It is free and it has basic code coverage analysis functionalities:

http://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage

For your information, profiling is also available:

xdebug.org/docs/profiler

(This should be a hyperlink!!! It only allows me to post one hyperlink per answer because I'm a new user... sigh...)

Hope this helps!

Kenji

Answer (score 0):

Compuware's DevPartner tools can do this. I'm not sure, but you may need to manually merge the results of multiple test runs.

Answer (score 0):

My company, Semantic Designs, offers a PHP test coverage tool that can do this just fine:
http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PHPTestCoverage.jsp

You set up the coverage collection, and then run your manual tests.
You can group your manual tests into a single test coverage collection,
or treat them separately, merging their results together later
using the coverage display tool.

Comment: Downvoter: can you provide an explicit reason for downvoting? This directly answers the OP's question.